# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'DoCmd'

Tags: python, ms-access

Having trouble figuring out what I'm doing wrong. Here is the code:

```
import smtplib
import win32api,time
import pypyodbc
from win32com.client import Dispatch

DbName = 'C:/Users/billybob643/Documents/Database1.accb'
Access = Dispatch("Access.Application")
Access.OpenCurrentDatabase(DbName)
DbAccess = Access.CurrentDb()
DbAccess.DoCmd.RunMacro("00")
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This error is telling you that `Access.CurrentDb()` returned None.

Comment: You are missing a `d` in your path `DbName = 'C:/Users/billybob643/Documents/Database1.acc` **d** `b'`. Typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DoCmd` is a member of the Access [Application object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/application-object-access).

Reference it via the `Access.Application` object variable you created ...

```
Access.DoCmd.RunMacro("00")
```

Comment: Thanks! This along with fixing the typo that ComputerVersteher found fixed it.